# Update mysql but only last digit of number

Tags: php, mysql

I am simply updating a database with a number, but I only want the last digit of the number to actually update. I am not sure whether to do this in PHP or MySql.

Code: (not full code posted, but relevant)

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

$N_Score = $_POST['N_Score'];
$A_Score = $_POST['A_Score'];

$sql = "UPDATE scores SET N_Score = $N_Score, A_Score = $A_Score";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

<form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "2"> 

<tr>
<td width = "10"><?php echo $N_Team; ?> Score:</td>
<td><input name = "N_Score" type = "text" id = "N_Score" value="<?php echo $N_Score; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width = "10"><?php echo $A_Team; ?> Score:</td>
<td><input name = "A_Score" type = "text" id = "A_Score" value="<?php echo $A_Score; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

So, in the form, I enter the score for the `N_Team` and `A_Team` like so:

`N_Team: 21` & `A_Team: 34`

I only want the last digit to actually go in to the update of the sql string, so in the database it would look like so:

`N_Team: 1` & `A_Team: 4`

Comment: So are you effectively trying to set the score to [`value % 10`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php)?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: Why not? As per your example, `21 % 10 = 1`, and `34 % 10 = 4`.

Comment: You didn't necessarily word it like that before you edited your first comment, but yea I guess you have a point.

Comment: Personally, I'd be doing it that way - you're working with numbers, so it makes sense to use a numeric operation if it's available rather than using substrings. If a non-number is posted back to your backend, that should be treated as an error anyway. It'd be naturally more resilient to input error, i.e. posting back "a1" with a substring approach could potentially update your database with "1" when it should really fail.

Comment: But  `var_dump('a1'%10);` [prints `int(0)`](https://3v4l.org/JimBi) without a warning/notice as well. So, this alone won't fix that particular problem. (The possibly different value ranges of php and mysql data types are probably not a concerne here....)

Comment: @VolkerK, good point. I'm, coming from a more strongly typed language and didn't realise how relaxed PHP is about type coercion. I guess you'd need to use `is_int` or compare `(int)a1` to `a1`, in which case there's no real advantage to my numeric approach anyway!

Comment: `you'd need to use is_int` - since the http parameters are strings (even if they denote numerical literals) you'd need something like ctype_digit. But yes, php is relaxed in that way just as if you'd use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) and ignore the endptr - ooops, that exactly what is happening under the hood ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$N_Score = substr($_POST['N_Score'], -1);
$A_Score = substr($_POST['A_Score'], -1);
```

This assumes the values are non-zero length, you might want some error handling.

You may also want to think about protecting yourself from SQL injection.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I knew it was simple. This is just a experiment, not public. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This will return the last char of the string.

```
$N_Score = substr($_POST['N_Score'], -1);
$A_Score = substr($_POST['A_Score'], -1);
```

Perhaps you could protect the integrity of your system by escaping the user input:

```
$N_Score = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['N_Score'], -1));
$A_Score = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['A_Score'], -1));
```

You also may want to switch from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`, which is improved and better to use.

Remember that if the string's size is 0 then the code will throw an error for "no value at position -1" or something.

So you better check if the string contains something before adding to the database.

Something like:

```
if ($_POST['N_Score'] != "" and $_POST['A_Score'] != "")
{
    $N_Score = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['N_Score'], -1));
    $A_Score = mysql_real_escape_string(substr($_POST['A_Score'], -1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just accepting oroboto's answer because he was first.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

$N_Score = substr($_POST['N_Score'], -1);
$A_Score = substr($_POST['A_Score'], -1);

$sql = "UPDATE scores SET N_Score = $N_Score, A_Score = $A_Score";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

<form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "2"> 

<tr>
   <td width = "10"><?php echo $N_Team; ?> Score:</td>
   <td><input name = "N_Score" type = "text" id = "N_Score" value="<?php echo $N_Score; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td width = "10"><?php echo $A_Team; ?> Score:</td>
   <td><input name = "A_Score" type = "text" id = "A_Score" value="<?php echo $A_Score; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```